# Hyperledger Composer: Add participant using data from HTML form

Tags: html, node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Let's say i have a signup page that allows a user to create a new participant by inserting the relevant data into an HTML form (ex: firstName, lastName, email, etc). Something like this:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="/myurl">
  <label for ="firstName">First Name</label>
  <input type = "text" name="firstName">
  <label for ="lastName">Last Name</label>
  <input type = "text" name="lastName">
  <label for ="email">Email</label>
  <input type = "text" name="email">
```

After the user submits the form i want to send the data into a node.js file (let's call it addParticipant.js) that creates a new participant using this data by doing something similar to what's described here: [Adding Participants](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/participant-add).

From what i understand i can use express and body-parser to handle POST requests in node.js.

My question is, where do i place the "addParticipant.js" file and how do i call it from the form? Should it be in my business network's /lib directory? If so, should `/myurl` in the form look like ~/lib/addParticipant?

Answer (score 0):

you can probably have a listener for new signups in a server process and do something like the following REST API post to the REST server, with the participant data POSTed, eg.

```
return this.httpClient.post('http://myrestserver:3001/api/org.acme.sample.Trader', trader).toPromise();
```

where `Trader` participant captured is something like:

```
const trader = {
  $class: 'org.acme.sample.Trader',
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  email: 't1@acme.net'
};
```